# I can't create New Project on Visual Web Developer 2008 Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

I can't create New Project on my Visual Web Developer 2008 Express with SP1.
(I can only create New Website)

My colleague has the exact same version (if you go to Help - About) but they can create both New Website and New Project.

I am trying to do this tutorial on MVC that also says that you can do it on Web Developer Express (http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-21-cs.aspx)

How do you enable New Project on Visual Web Developer 2008 Express?

http://www.yart.com.au/junk/hardi%20temp/vs1.gif 
http://www.yart.com.au/junk/hardi%20temp/vs2.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Tools->Import and Export Settings, then "Reset all settings".  The New Project menu option then magically appears.

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/06/01/asp-net-mvc-support-with-visual-web-developer-2008-express.aspx), the ability to add web application projects was added in SP 1 of VWD. Try downloading and installing it again.

Comment: I have already uninstalled and reinstalled the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it:

1. Select File/New Project
2. Add it to your existing solution

And Bob's your uncle!